# How to cut box corner Using CSS with transparent background?

Tags: css, sass, rounded-corners

I want to cut left top corner of a box using CSS like this.

[image]

keep in mind that background is transparent.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nearly the same solution as [OriDrori's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44994117/1548895) but more flexible (if you need fixed-width cutted corner).

This gradient will look the same regardless of `.card` `width` and `height`.

```css
body {
  background: purple;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 20px, white 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
```

Comment: @LGSon just as a side cooment, right bottom and 135deg are equivalent only if the aspect ratio of the container is 1:1. However, it's difficult to say which one is better if the OP doesn't state he intended behaviour on non square elements

Comment: Works. But what if you also want to use background on the card? For example to give a gradient background to the card itself?

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock You can use modern `clip-path` solution if you are OK with its browser support. For instance, Nick suggested [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44994129/1548895).

Comment: I need to support Edge

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock Then the best option would be to use SVG background here.

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock Also note that Microsoft Edge team [is working on implementing `clip-path`](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/6261341-css-masking), so in nearest future you can change your code to use this approach.

Comment: Thanks. Would you also recommend svg background for a window that the user can change size of by dragging its edges? And then making sure the corner stays the same size by the other dimensions change

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock I've [asked about your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53742988/1548895), here's [the first solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53743308/1548895) at the moment.

Comment: wow this was the easiest solution i found that worked.  thank you

Answer (score 7):

You can use a simple [linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) for that:

```css
body {
  background: purple;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 5%, white 5%);
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use clip-path 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

and use something like this:

```css
div#test{
 background:red;
 width:200px;
 height: 200px;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(22% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 20%);
clip-path: polygon(22% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 20%);
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: @AmirUrRehman Note though, this solution has bad browser support (which I suggest, Nick, you always add info about when posting answers that doesn't at least work cross all the latest browsers)

Answer (score 4):

With a pseudo and `transform` you can do that, and it has good browser support (from IE9)

```css
body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/400/300) center / cover;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% + 25px);             /*  25px is height/width of the cut  */
  top: calc(50% + 25px);
  width: 141.5%;
  height: 141.5%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%)  rotate(45deg);
  background: #eee;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

As pointed out, if you need it to scale on different aspect ratio's, use this

```css
body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/400/300) center / cover;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 1000%;
  height: 5000%;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(25px,-50%);   /* 25px for the cut height/width */
  transform-origin: left top;
  background: #eee;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't satisfy the original ask of using a transparent background. It works good for solid color because it sits on top of the main element.

Comment: @NeilMonroe This answer works even with an image behind, and/or a semi-transparent color on the overlay. See my update. Or did you mean something else?